# HTTP errors on crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Can we get HTTP errors with error codes on Crashlytics like in NewRelic ?

We can see Crashlytics give crashes but can't observes any HTTP errors resulting due to Rest service calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Crashlytics, which is a part of Fabric, does not capture non-fatal HTTP errors. However, you can capture these in a couple of different ways. I'll separate out by platform:

**Android**
You can log [Caught Exceptions](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html#caught-exceptions) by adding a call to `Crashlytics.logException(e);` like this for any exception you wish to capture.

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here!
}
```

Alternatively, you could capture in aggregate the number of times these events are happening using an [Answers custom event](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html#custom-event).

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Rest HTTP Error")
      .putCustomAttribute("Response code", 504));
```

**iOS**

You can log [NSErrors](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/logged-errors.html#logged-errors) by adding a call to `[CrashlyticsKit recordError:error];` or `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)z for any error you wish to capture.

Alternatively, you could also capture in aggregate the number of times these events are happening using an [Answers custom event](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/answers/answers-events.html#custom-event).

```
    // Objective-C
[Answers logCustomEventWithName:@"Rest HTTP Error"
                      customAttributes:@{
                          @"Custom Number" : @504}];
// Swift
Answers.logCustomEventWithName("Rest HTTP Error",
                      customAttributes: [
                          "Custom Number": 504])
```

Comment: Please suggest a proper way to add JSON responses to the custom event, so it will be convenient viewable from the Answers dashboard

Comment: You'd need to take the JSON response and convert it to a string. In Java, I'd use the following:  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   json.toString();
and log that String value. Do note that custom event attributes are limited to 100 characters within the dashboard though you can hover to find the full value.

Comment: Thanks, I already converting to string, but still only a part of string value visible by hover

Comment: In that case, can you share a link to where this is happening or email into support(at)fabric(dot)io?